# Video won't stop after closing it with the button

Tags: html

How can I stop the video while closing it?

Can someone give me some solution or new code for this?

```
<div class="video-player" id="videoPlayer">
            <video width="100%" controls autoplay id="myVideo">
                <source src="filmy/1.%20No%20Roots%20-%20Alice%20Merton.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video> 
            <img src="images/close.png" class="close-btn"
            onclick="stopVideo()">
        </div>  
        <script>
            var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer"); 
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
            
            function stopVideo(){
                videoPlayer.style.display = "none";
            } 
            
            function playVideo(file){
                myVideo.src = file;
                videoPlayer.style.display = "block";
            }
            
        </script>
```

And here is where I declare video:

```
<div class="small-img-row">
    <div class="small-img">
        <img src="images/Sk%C5%82ad%20Artur%202.jpg" width="170px" height="100px">
        <img src="images/play.png" class="play-btn" onclick="playVideo('filmy/2. Dance Monkey - Tones and I.mp4')">
    </div>
    <p>Dance Monkey - Tones and I</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `element.pause();` in JS. Also I highly recommend not to use `.style` in JS in 2022 anymore. The modern approach is to use `.classList` + `.add('class-name')`, `.remove('class-name')` or `.toggle('class-name')` and apply the changes through CSS.

Comment: But where do i need to put this pause? Cause i put it in funtion stopVideo and its not working. Im totally newbie at JS so i dont really know what to do exactly.